# How pseudocapacitors work?

Tags: electricity, electrochemistry

I have read that pseudocapacitors are combined of a carbon electrode and a metal oxide one.

On the carbon electrode simply a double layer is built up and on the  other some chemical actions(redox) happens.

I was wondering how the chemical reaction happens and how this is possible when we have just on electrode in the reaction?

Comment: Does not this Wikipedia article answer your questions? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocapacitance

Comment: thank you.Ive read that.can you describe more?

Comment: Your first question is about Chemistry and the answer to your second question is that there are two electrodes.  One electrode is the one where the electric charge transfer occurs between the electrolyte and the electrode and the other electrode is the electrolyte and whatever is electrically connected to it..